# Error in Codeigniter PHP STRIPE lib payment (using a card number for a declined response_

Tags: codeigniter, stripe-payments

I'm trying to catch errors in codeigniter 3 by using stripe php library (last version)
So, when I use a correct testing card number the payment goes ok, but when I use a test declined card number for testing purposes I'm getting the error:
Type: Stripe\Exception\CardException

Message: Your card was declined.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjBw6.png)

Filename: /opt/lampp/htdocs/plataforma_asociaciones/application/third_party/stripe-php-old/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php

Line Number: 38

Backtrace:

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/plataforma_asociaciones/application/third_party/stripe-php-old/lib/Exception/CardException.php
Line: 38
Function: factory

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/plataforma_asociaciones/application/third_party/stripe-php-old/lib/ApiRequestor.php
Line: 195
Function: factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code is only catching a subset of all possible errors.  Have a look at [the PHP error handling sample snippet in the Stripe API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling?lang=php):

```php
try {
  // Use Stripe's library to make requests...
} catch(\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
  // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Exception\CardException will be caught
  echo 'Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . '\n';
  echo 'Type is:' . $e->getError()->type . '\n';
  echo 'Code is:' . $e->getError()->code . '\n';
  // param is '' in this case
  echo 'Param is:' . $e->getError()->param . '\n';
  echo 'Message is:' . $e->getError()->message . '\n';
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\RateLimitException $e) {
  // Too many requests made to the API too quickly
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException $e) {
  // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\AuthenticationException $e) {
  // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
  // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiConnectionException $e) {
  // Network communication with Stripe failed
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
  // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
  // yourself an email
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
}
```

`ApiErrorException` is only one type of exception among many.  If you want to handle other types of exceptions you need to add code to do so.

Comment: thanks!!! it worked! and I identified that you need to add the create client method inside the try as well as the create charge., Thanks a lot Justin! I appreciate your help!